# Nothing there in the Active Tool drop down

Tags: texture-painting

I’m really new to blender and whenever I click the Active Tool drop down in the tab Tool of Texture Paint, nothing happens. In the tutorial I’m following, there is supposed to be a bunch of options that show up. I’ve tried reopening blender and I’ve opened a new project where these options do show up. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Blender SE! Including screenshots makes it easier for others to help you, as is including the original video and timestamp of the tutorial you are referencing!

Comment: Did you click a tool in the tool bar that is in the 3d view? Once you click a tool, that tab fills with the corresponding information about the selected tool.